# Error: Taxa ".." is not present in tree 1 / error in BayesTrait v.4

Tags: linux

I am trying to run the program BayesTrait v4. in a Linux terminal. However, every time I use the following command line:

```
./BayesTraitsV4 tree_file.nex data_file.txt
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Taxa .... is not present in tree 1
```

For a better understanding, find attached the tree file(nexus format) and data file (txt format). I would appreciate any advice to fix this error, please.

[tree_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WpavJ7GFwSolPYDKsJLsSM4JQXiieGga/view?usp=sharing),
[data file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TtfFBAM2TIXeNkJk7nWXxANoViSI3zq1/view?usp=share_link)

I have checked the spelling of each taxon, and I also have checked the valid translate block.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, where BayesTraitsV4 seemed to not recognize any of the translate block. I was initially trying to directly use the IQTree .treefile output, which includes bootstrap values and was initially unrooted. Even when making the .trees nexus file look exactly like the examples, it was giving me the same error of not finding the taxa in the tree.

What I did was the following:

1. Open the IQTree .treefile in FigTree, re-rooted in here, then exported the tree as a Nexus file (.trees). The bootstrap values seem to not be saved after this action.
2. Opened this .trees file into RStudio with read.nexus.
    `readtree<-read.nexus("FileName.trees")`
3. Saved this via write.nexus again to get the translate block.
   `write.nexus(readtree,file = "NAME.trees")`
4. Opened this new .trees file in Text Edit, removing the first line with the R information, and the entire TAXA section. So the top of the .trees file then reads

```
#NEXUS
BEGIN TREES
        TRANSLATE
                1        Name...
                2        ...
```

This ended up working for me, hope it works for you!

FURTHER EDITS:
If wanting to just use the IQTree consensus tree (I only have a consensus tree), I loaded the .treefile, rooted it with `ape::root` function, copied it `as.phylo`, and made a copy of the phylo object again (so I don't loose information) to remove the node labels (bootstrap values) `newtree$node.label<-NULL`. When I saved this as a nexus .tree file, and again removed the R info and Begin Taxa sections, BayesTraits4 ran smoothly. Now, this gives me the same node numbers I will use for the graphical representation.